# How to print date in the format of mm/dd/yyyy in VB

Tags: date, vb6

I need to print the date in the format of mm/dd/yyyy.
if the date is 4/24/2009 it should print the date as 04/24/2009.
that is zero padding is also needed..
I used date function to get the current date...but the date is getting in the format of m/dd/yyyy...

Comment: Which version of VB are you talking about?

Comment: `Date()` doesn't return it in any format. It returns a date which then uses your current locale settings when it is displayed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tested in the immediate window and is working for me (output as a comment)

```
Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy") '04/29/2009
Format(Date, "MM/dd/yyyy") '04/29/2009
Format(CStr(Now), "MM/dd/yyyy") '04/29/2009
Format(Date$, "MM/dd/yyyy") '04/29/2009
Format(CDate(Date), "MM/dd/yyyy")'04/29/2009
```

So whether it is string or datetime should not matter.

Edit: Saw your comment to Fredrik. It doesn't matter how it looks like when you save it to the db table (column date format would be a property of the db and not your program's (or vb's) responsibility). Just format the value as and when you retrieve it from the db.

Comment: if you try Msgbox(Format(Date, "MM/dd/yyyy")) it will work.. but i tried like... Dim dt as Date d = Format(Date, "MM/dd/yyyy") for this it wont work.

Comment: The date data type, if unformatted, always displays as per system regional settings. You just need to format it when you want to display it.

Comment: Like what Fredrik said, even VB stores dates as a number, not a literal m/d/y string. Explanation of the storage here: http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_misc/algorithms/article.php/c7495

Comment: thanks a lot guys...
lastly i changed the data type of column to string...
now it is working fine...

Answer (score 3):

Note that the "/" character in date formatting functions has a special meaning, as "date separator". This means that i may be replaced with the date separator for the current locale that the program is executed in (here in Sweden it would be replaced with "-" for instance). In order to ensure that you do indeed get the "/" character in the output, I think this would work (I don't have a VB installation to verify with):

```
Format(date, "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy")
```

Comment: yes you are write this will work only if the date type is of format string... but i am using Date format...
i am having one table..that has one column of data type date
so even if i convert the date to string as you mentioned.it will automatically will get convert to date ven i insert the value to tabel..
for eg: 
dim dt as string
dt=Format(Date,"mm/dd/yyyy")'this will convert to 04/24/2009
but ven i insert this to table it will convert back to 4/24/2009 because that particular column is of type date

Comment: The reason it converts back when put in the table is that the table does not store the date as a string, but as a date object (which deep down is a numeric value). What you see is only a textual representation of it. I guess your DB software will automatically use your locales default to show the value to you. If you want it displayed in some other way in your application, you will need to format it before putting it into the control used for showing it.

Answer (score 2):

just for the record, escaping the slash will work 
**`Format(dt,"MM\/dd\/yyyy")`**

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code:

```
Format(dt,"MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enter date in whatever format it will convert default value so do one thing that in access change your data type date/time to text then it can't affect to your work sure.

Answer (score 0):

I also use VB6 and need to format date in my txt report

this works for me

```
Format$(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd-00.00.00")
```

but only if I declare date as string

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this also depending upon your requirement

```
Dim strDate As String
Dim strDate1() As String
strDate = FormatDateTime(Now, vbGeneralDate)

If InStr(strDate, " ") > 0 Then
    strDate1 = Split(strDate, " ")
    Dim datDate1 As Date
    If Month(strDate1(0)) < 10 Then
        txtDate.Text = "0" + strDate1(0)
    Else
        txtDate.Text = strDate1(0)
    End If

Else

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatting DateTime as a string is straightforward. Often we use format patterns like "HH." But methods like ToShortDateString are also useful.

Example. First we get the current time through DateTime.Now. When you execute these code examples, the current DateTime will be different on your computer.
Here: A format string beginning with MMM (for the month) is used. Look at how the pattern matches up to the output of the program.

**VB.NET program that uses format string with DateTime**

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        ' Use current time.
        ' ... Use a format.
        ' ... Write to console.
        Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim format As String = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy"
        Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(format))
    End Sub
End Module

**Output**

Feb Tue 21 13:26 2017

Answer (score -1):

```
strDate = Format(strDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
BillTime = Format(BillTime, "hh:mm:ss")
```